# Select SUM field and other column from join query

Tags: mysql

I have these tables.

1. Level Table **levels**(id, name)
2. Student Table **students**(id, name, level_id)
3. Payment Type Table **payment_types**(id, name) e.g Tuition Feee, Uniform
4. Payment table **payments**(id, student_id, payment_type_id, amount, created_at)
5. Level Payment Table **payment_fees**(level_id, payment_type_id, amount) e.g Amount for Tuition free for a particular level

I need a **single query** that will fetch **total** payment details for all students in a specified level(level_id) and also show the payment fee for each student(gotten using the student level_id to lookup **payment_fees** table

I have this query:

```
select students.id, students.name name, levels.name class, MAX(payments.created_at) date, SUM(payments.amount) amount 
from `students` 
left join `payments` on `students`.`id` = `payments`.`student_id` and `payments`.`payment_type_id` = '1'
inner join `levels` on `levels`.`id` = `students`.`level_id`
group by `students`.`id`
```

This works great [Here is the GUI presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubHdR.png)**(check real life query at the button of the page)** and [Here is the json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWZfQ.png) but I need one more column **total** which is the payment fee(from payment_fees **amount** column) for the student level and specified payment_type_id so I can compare the sum with the **total** and know if the student has completed his/her payment or not.

I've tried this but working with this error:

```
select students.id, students.name name, levels.name class, MAX(payments.created_at) date, SUM(payments.amount) amount, payment_fees.amount as total 
from `students` 
left join `payments` on `students`.`id` = `payments`.`student_id` and `payments`.`payment_type_id` = '1'
inner join `levels` on `levels`.`id` = `students`.`level_id`
inner join 'payment_fees' on 'payment_fees.level_id' = 'students.level_id'
```

But it's not working... it's giving this error: [Here is the error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKavH.png)

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'schooladminer.payment_type_fees.amount' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: It seems highly implausible that 'this works great'! See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  The query won't even run.

Comment: You can share what errors you are encountering

Comment: Thanks for the response..  i've edited the question to show the result of the working query and the error i encountered with the second query.

Comment: What i need is another column named **total** with is the data from the payment_fees table for the currently students **level_id** and **payment_type_id**. Thanks

Comment: @Eric try to not pile ???, just one ? is enough. There's no need to overwhelm the OP with question marks.

Comment: @Emmanuel Learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  Then maybe you can solve this problem.

Comment: @Eric. I know that's where the error is coming from. I've tried all my best to make it work with **GROUP BY students.id** but not working properly. Can you kindly help me look through the query and suggest how I should use the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Eric is right.. i've take my time to look into the GROUP BY and i've been able to make it to work. Thank.

Comment: I'll update the answer for others to learn from it as well... Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can separate things by using sub-query

```
select T3.student_name,T3.Level_name,T3.payment_name,T3.payment as student_payment,created_at,

    T4.payment_name as Level_payment,LevelPayment from 
    (
    select student_name,Level_name,payment_name,sum(amount) as payment,max(created_at) as created_at from
    (
    select S.name as student_name,S.id as student_id,
    L.name as Level_name,L.level_id from students S
    left join levels L
    on S.level_id=L.id
    )T1
    left join 
    (
    select PT.name as payment_name,id, student_id, payment_type_id, amount, created_at  
    from payments P
    left join payment_types PT
    on P.payment_type_id=PT.id
    ) T2
    on T1.student_id=T2.student_id
    group by student_name,Level_name,payment_name,T1.student_id
    ) T3
    left join
    (
    select PT.name as payment_name,L.name as Level_name,l.level_id, payment_type_id, sum(amount) as LevelPayment from payment_fees PF
    left join
    payment_types PT
    on PF.payment_type_id=PT.id
    left join levels L on PF.level_id=L.id
    group by PT.name,L.name,L.level_id,payment_type_id
    ) T4 on T3.Level_name=T4.Level_name
```